# Finding Homography v/s Contour detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

The problem is to detect a known rectangular object in an image.
Which of the following is computationally less expensive:

1. Finding homography - For finding homography, we use the template of the known object to do feature matching.
2. Contour detection - We try to detect the biggest contour in the image. In this particular case we assume that the biggest contour will correspond to the known rectangular object we are trying to find.

In both the cases we do perspective transform after detecting the object to set the perspective.

NOTE: We are using Open-CV functions to find the homography and detecting contour.

Comment: Why don't you try timing it and seeing for yourself?  They're both valid approaches **assuming** that the image is known to have the template inside it.  If it doesn't, then neither of these methods will work.

Answer (score 3):

You should try finding the biggest contour. It's the simplest and will be far faster. You needs to detect Canny edges then find contours and find the one with the biggest area. However, it can fail if contours are unclear or if there is a bigger object as it doesn't consider shape. You can also apply  both of your ideas to get better results.

**EDIT:**

To reply your comment, you have *Canny edge + find contours + find biggest* against *find features + match features*

I think that the first combination is less computationally expensive. Moreover, there is a good implementation of squares/rectangle detection [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp).

However, if the contours of the rectangle are not clear, and if moreover the rectangle is highly textured, you should get better results with features matching.

Comment: If you can give me a rough proof or argument in terms of time complexity or something like what makes contour detection using canny's edge detection faster than finding homography, then it will be great.